# shiro - "Error listenerStart" error while starting

Tags: shiro

I am trying to integrate Shiro based on an excellent article penned by BalusC in my application. I added required JAR files (shiro-core-1.2.1.jar, shiro-web-1.2.1.jar, slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar and slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar). Also modified web.xml. and added shiro.ini file. However, it throws the following error on JBOSS EAP 6.0.

3:32:34,470 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-3) Error listenerStart
13:32:34,470 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-3) Context [/FedSep] startup failed due to previous errors

Comment: no stack trace? Can you post the whole log from starting the server / application (whatever triggers the error)? It says there were `previous errors`...